# Pyspark - grouped data with count() and sorting possible?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with location and gender as string values and i want to look at the top 20 locations with male and female count splits, in descending order. This is the code I have so far but its not sorted in desc. How can i do that?

```
display(Markdown("**Top 20 locations** with highest active users split by sex ratio (in \%):"))

pivotDF = datingDF.groupBy("location").pivot("sex"). count()
pivotDF.show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------+----+----+
|location                 |f   |m   |
+-------------------------+----+----+
|mill valley, california  |176 |139 |
|london, united kingdom   |null|1   |
|west oakland, california |3   |4   |
|freedom, california      |1   |null|
|columbus, ohio           |null|1   |
|rochester, michigan      |1   |null|
|mountain view, california|106 |278 |
|magalia, california      |null|1   |
|san rafael, california   |340 |415 |
|nicasio, california      |1   |2   |
|santa cruz, california   |null|5   |
|moss beach, california   |3   |5   |
|muir beach, california   |null|1   |
|larkspur, california     |35  |45  |
|san quentin, california  |1   |1   |
|kentfield, california    |7   |11  |
|montara, california      |9   |3   |
|brooklyn, new york       |1   |2   |
|utica, michigan          |null|1   |
|burlingame, california   |154 |207 |
+-------------------------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`orderBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.orderBy)

> `orderBy(*cols, **kwargs)`
>
> Returns a new DataFrame sorted by the specified column(s).
>
> Parameters
>
> ***cols*** – list of Column or column names to sort by.
>
> ***ascending*** – boolean or list of boolean (default True). Sort ascending vs. descending. Specify list for multiple sort orders. If a
> list is specified, length of the list must equal length of the cols.

```
datingDF.groupBy("location").pivot("sex").count().orderBy("F","M",ascending=False)
```

Incase you want one ascending and the other one descending you can do something like this.

```
datingDF.groupBy("location").pivot("sex").count().orderBy("F","M",ascending=[1,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get how exactly you want to sort, by sum of `f` and `m` columns or by multiple columns.

1. For the sum:

```
pivotDF = pivotDF.orderBy((F.col('f') + F.col('m')).desc())
```

2. For multiple columns:

```
pivotDF = pivotDF.orderBy(F.col('f').desc(), F.col('m').desc())
```